# filling new dataframe column using corresponding past indices values and specific unique column values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, for-loop, dataframe

I want to know whether there is an elegant way of doing, what i did in a very long and i believe very crude manner. Lets say we have a dataframe where we have two columns: 'col1','col2'. Number of rows are 13. 'Col1' contains three variables: 'a', 'b' and 'c'. 'col2' contain random numerical values. Now i want to create a new column named 'teststat' which contains the value contained in 'col2' by variable in 'col1' the last time it occurred or is equal to the present value if this is it's first occurrence. For example if if 'a' occurs in row 0,1,4,6 and 12 and it's col2  value at these index locations is 32, 432 , 56, 4 and 34 then the value of test stat at these locations should be 32, 32, 432, 56 and 4.

sample dataset of what i want:

```
index   col1    teststat    col2
  0      a         32.0       32
  1      a         32.0      432
  2      b        433.0      433
  3      c          4.0        4
  4      a        432.0       56
  5      c          4.0       64
  6      a         56.0        4
  7      b        433.0      535
  8      c         64.0      643
  9      c        643.0      356
 10      b        535.0       32
 11      b         32.0      535
 12      a          4.0       34
```

I have used the following code which uses the logic of storing the indices of where particular value out of 'a', 'b', 'c' occurs and then writing individual codes with for loops but I can see that this can become a problem while scaling up, for example if instead of only 3 unique values in 'col1' we have 500+ separate unique values. I want a solution/logic on what could be done for that scenario. I have added the code for what i have done below:

**cell[1]**:

```
for vals in list(df['col1'].unique()):
    if vals=='a':
        idxa = df.index[df['col1']=='a']
    if vals=='b':
        idxb = df.index[df['col1']=='b']
    if vals=='c':
        idxc = df.index[df['col1']=='c']
```

**cell[2]**:

```
for i in range(len(idxa)):
    if i==0:
        df.loc[idxa[i],'test_stat']=df.loc[idxa[i],'col2']
    else:
        df.loc[idxa[i],'test_stat']=df.loc[idxa[i-1],'col2']


for i in range(len(idxb)):
    if i==0:
        df.loc[idxb[i],'test_stat']=df.loc[idxb[i],'col2']
else:
    df.loc[idxb[i],'test_stat']=df.loc[idxb[i-1],'col2']

for i in range(len(idxc)):
    if i==0:
        df.loc[idxc[i],'test_stat']=df.loc[idxc[i],'col2']
    else:
        df.loc[idxc[i],'test_stat']=df.loc[idxc[i-1],'col2']
```

Is there a more elegant/better way to do this? Any idea/help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use `groupby` with `shift`.

```
df['teststat'] = df.groupby('col1')['col2'].shift(1).fillna(df['col2'])

print(df[['col1', 'teststat', 'col2']])

    col1    teststat    col2
0      a        32.0      32
1      a        32.0     432
2      b       433.0     433
3      c         4.0       4
4      a       432.0      56
5      c         4.0      64
6      a        56.0       4
7      b       433.0     535
8      c        64.0     643
9      c       643.0     356
10     b       535.0      32
11     b        32.0     535
12     a         4.0      34
```

**Edit**

For your added question:

> Let's say, i want another column 'teststat2' which gives the difference between last 2 values for a particular value in 'col1'.

You can just do the following.

```
df['teststat2'] = df['col2'] - df['teststat']
df.loc[df['teststat2'] == 0, 'teststat2'] = df['col2']
print(df)

    col1    teststat    col2    teststat2
0      a        32.0      32         32.0
1      a        32.0     432        400.0
2      b       433.0     433        433.0
3      c         4.0       4          4.0
4      a       432.0      56       -376.0
5      c         4.0      64         60.0
6      a        56.0       4        -52.0
7      b       433.0     535        102.0
8      c        64.0     643        579.0
9      c       643.0     356       -287.0
10     b       535.0      32       -503.0
11     b        32.0     535        503.0
12     a         4.0      34         30.0
```

Comment: Good answer, `.shift(1)` should be `.shift()` :)

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution. It works and from what i can understand from above is that you are first shifting the index by 1 for grouping based on col1 for col2 values and then filling these values in the 'teststat' column. Okay now i have another question, which is an extension of this. Let's say,  i want another column 'teststat2' which gives the difference between last 2 values for a particular value in 'col1'. How to go about that, as from what i understand shift is only shifting the index but not storing that index. thank you for your help btw

Comment: like 'a' occurs in row 0,1,4,6 and 12 and it's col2 value at these index locations is 32, 432 , 56, 4 and 34 then teststat2 values should be 32(=32),400(=432-32),-376(=56-432) and 30(=34-4).

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, this seems to be the same as subtracting `df['teststat]` from `df['col2]`. Then you can just update the values where `df['teststat2]` is 0. See my edit.

Comment: Yes Ben checked your edit just now. Works like a charm. Thanks for your help. But now I have to strengthen my grip on transform and groupby operations. Very handy indeed.